# How to connect to a Postgresql database using .NET Core CLR

Tags: c#, coreclr

How do i connect to a Postgresql database using .NET C# Core CLR?

I keep finding references to EF7 and SQL Server, but nothing on Postgresql.

Comment: What about [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/)?

Comment: @xtnd8 Depends on System.Data which is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npgsql does have a branch that [works with the CoreCLR](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/coreclr.html), however it is currently in alpha/unstable mode since .Net Core isn't exactly stable itself at the moment. But in case you missed the announcement, like I did, Npgsql now works with Entity Framework 7. Information on the Entity Framework 7 provider can be found [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ef7.html).

Comment: Both links are dead.

Comment: Yes but so is Entity Framework 7, since it's now Entity Framework Core. But updated link: http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html